# Nhibernate, determine if lazyloaded collection has been retrieved yet

Tags: c#, nhibernate, iteration, lazy-loading

I have a validation engine that iterates through all the properties of an object and checks if they are valid.

If I get an Entity and change a simple property and run it through the engine it hydrates all of the lazyloaded collections.

In other words it gets the collection and iterates through the entities in that collection.  If the collection has already been retrieved than that is fine but if it has not been retrieved then there is no reason it would be invalid so there is no reason to go get it.

In short, can I inspect a collection and see if it has been retrieved yet.  If I can do that then I can skip or iterate that collection accordingly.

Comment: The `Active Record` pattern, a C# `ref` or a `public static` reference could help you determine if this object has already been evaluated. Another option is to implement the `IClonable` and keep an empty clone of every evaluated Entity in memory so you know you evaluated it before or you can just keep a list of the Entities' hash codes. BTW if Nhibernate has already your lazy-loaded collections in memory it will not load them again unless you exit than context or leave the ISession.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NHibernateUtil`:

```
var isInitialized = NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(entity.Collection);
```

Comment: Yea this is what I ended up with. The problem was that I was using reflection and doing IsInitialized on the the property rather than the object or something like that.  I had to do getValue on the prop and then check that.  When oding IsInitalized on the prop it was returning true, on the value it was properly returning false.